# Why cannot I load DolphinDB Python API 3.8 in windows?

Tags: python, api, dolphindb

Environment: Windows, Python 3.8.0

`pip install dolphindb` has been executed, but it failed to import dolphindb in Python.

```
>>> import dolphindb as ddb

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "D:\app\conda\envs\test3\lib\site-packages\dolphindb\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>

    from .session import session

  File "D:\app\conda\envs\test3\lib\site-packages\dolphindb\session.py", line 18, in <module>

    import dolphindbcpp  as ddbcpp

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing dolphindbcpp: DLL initialization failed.
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Did you activate the environment test3? You're running python in the base env.

Answer (score 0):

DolphinDB Python API supports python 3.8 in conda environment only on Windows at present.

You may refer to Python API for DolphinDB (https://github.com/dolphindb/api_python3) for details.

Please set python 3.8 > 3.8.0 in conda and then execute pip install dolphindb.`enter code here`